# MVC3 - Cannot select item in DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to learn MVC3 and in one exercise I'm doing I have defined a DropDownListFor like this one:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Animal,
new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(Model.AvailableValues, "Value",
"Text", Model.Animal))
```

Where Model.Animal is of type AnimalEnum:

```
public enum AnimalEnum
{
    Cat,
    Dog,
    Fox,
    Aardvark
}
```

And AvailableValues is defined as:

```
var model = definition.Settings.GetModel<AnimalTypePart>();
model.AvailableValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof (AnimalEnum))
            .Cast<int>()
            .Select(i => 
                new {
                    Text = Enum.GetName(typeof (AnimalEnum), i), 
                    Value = i
                });
```

My problem is that I'm able to save correctly the value that I select on the dropdownlist, but when I display again the dropdownlist it doesn't show the saved value but instead it always shows the first one of the list (Cat). I also tried to put "(int)Model.Animal" as the last parameter of DropDownListFor, that corresponds to the integer Value associated to each option, but it doesn't work either. Debugging I can confirm that all parameters of DropDownListFor have the correct value when the helper is called.
Can you help me to have the dropdownlist automatically show the saved value when I visualize the page?

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the index as value in the selected param, given that you are using the index of the Enum item as value in the select:

```
var model = definition.Settings.GetModel<AnimalTypePart>();
model.AvailableValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof (AnimalEnum))
        .Cast<int>()
        .Select(i => 
            new {
                Text = Enum.GetName(typeof (AnimalEnum), i), 
                Value = i,
                Selected = i == (int)model.Animal
            });
```

As well, the last parameter for `DropDownListFor` is `htmlAttributes`, you are passing `Model.Animal`, remove It.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. AvailableValues is a IEnumerable<dynamic>, so with your code I obtain a list where every element has the selected property on itself. And Model.Animal is the last parameter of SelectList, not of DropDownListFor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need define a property that is going to hold the *selected value* within your model.

This property also needs to exist in the list of values that are available to select within the available options.

This way your model will rebind to the selected value automatically if it is set in the model and also hold the selected value in the post.

Here is an example of how to do that.

**[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YPZfHO)**

**Model**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedAnimalId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableValues { get; set; }

}
```

Pls note the `SelectedAnimalId` property which will hold the selected value which is a string. This is the converted int property of the enum i.e. cat = 0, dog = 1 etc that is held within the values of the selected list items.

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();          

        model.AvailableValues = PopulatedDropDown;
        model.SelectedAnimalId = "1";

        return View(model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // Save it to db and rebind the selected
        model.AvailableValues = PopulatedDropDown;  


        return View(model);
    }

    // helper property to populate from the enum
    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PopulatedDropDown
    {           
            get {
                var enumList =  Enum.GetValues(typeof (AnimalEnum))
            .Cast<int>()
            .Select(i => 
                    new SelectListItem {
                    Text = Enum.GetName(typeof (AnimalEnum), i), 
                    Value = i.ToString()

                });
                return enumList;
            }
    }
```

In the get a list of available options are populated and the `SelectedAnimalId` is set to the second one in the list. Note the rebind in the working example.

The post simply passes the model through and displays which item has been selected in the view.

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
 {  
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedAnimalId,
Model.AvailableValues)
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
}
                Selected Item:
                @Model.SelectedAnimalId
```

The above simply sets the `SelectedAnimalId` as the first parameter, then uses the bound list as the options.